# Export tensorflow graph with export_saved_model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to train and deploy simplified Quick, Draw! classifier from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/recurrent_quickdraw) on Google Cloud. I've managed to train model in GC, now stuck at deploying it, more precisely, at [creating serving input functions](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/deploying-models#creating_serving_input_functions).

I'm following instructions from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#using_savedmodel_with_estimators) and having tough times trying to understand what type of input tensor should be.

Error:

> TypeError: Failed to convert object of type  to Tensor. Contents: SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("ParseExample/ParseExample:0", shape=(?, 2), dtype=int64), values=Tensor("ParseExample/ParseExample:1", shape=(?,), dtype=float32), dense_shape=Tensor("ParseExample/ParseExample:2", shape=(2,), dtype=int64)). Consider casting elements to a supported type.

Serving function:

```
def serving_input_receiver_fn():
  serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=[None], name='input_tensors')
  receiver_tensors = {'infer_inputs': serialized_tf_example}
  features = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_spec)
  return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_tensors)
```

Feature specification:

```
feature_spec = {
    "ink": tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.float32),
    "shape": tf.FixedLenFeature([2], dtype=tf.int64)
}
```

Input layer:

```
def _get_input_tensors(features, labels):
  shapes = features["shape"]
  lengths = tf.squeeze(
    tf.slice(shapes, begin=[0, 0], size=[params.batch_size, 1]))
  inks = tf.reshape(features["ink"], [params.batch_size, -1, 3])

  if labels is not None:
    labels = tf.squeeze(labels)
  return inks, lengths, labels
```

Code of model and training data were taken [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/recurrent_quickdraw#run_the_tutorial_code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def serving_input_receiver_fn():
  ink = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, None, 3], name='ink')
  length = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int64, shape=[None, 1])
  features = {"ink": inks, "length": lengths}
  return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, features)
```

An example payload would be:

```
{"instances": [{"ink": [[0.1, 1.0, 2.0]], "length":[[1]]}]}
```

or as input to `gcloud predict --json-instances`:

```
{"ink": [[0.1, 1.0, 2.0]], "length":[[1]]}]
```

I didn't look into the actual code; if ink is generally going to hold a lot of floats, you may want to consider an alternative encoding system.

Comment: Thanks, added shape to features and disabled adding loss and optimizers for prediction mode and it worked!

Comment: happy to hear it!